# Postgresql select duplicate column by another column

Tags: postgresql

I have a data set like

```
ID STATUS SOURCE
1  new    data1
1  old    data2
2  old    data1
2  new    data2
```

and I want to be able to select those duplicates ID by the STATUS column and keep the SOURCE, the final list will be:

```
ID STATUS SOURCE
1  new    data1
2  new    data2
```

I can make the list of duplicate ID with something like:

```
select id, status, source 
from data
where id in (
select id
from data
group by id
having (count(* ) > 1)
```

then I can not find a way to filter by the status to remove the duplicates.

Thanks.

Comment: So, whenever there are two or more duplicate IDs, you want to keep the one with `status='new'`?

Comment: yes, and the rest of data in that row

Comment: If you want to get rid of the duplicates entirely, you can `DELETE FROM data WHERE status = 'old'`. If you only want to select, then you can just add another where condition `... WHERE status = 'new' AND ...`. This seems too obvious, though... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Raffael I interpret it as "get the new row if there is one, otherwise get the old row." *new* overrides *old*. Looks like primitive generation counting.

Comment: You could use Postgresql's `DISTINCT BY (id)` in conjunction with `ORDER BY status`. Applying an order to a column that can only contain the values `'new'` and `'old'` seems a bit odd, but it should work. A datetime column would seem more natural. (Then it would be a `greatest-n-per-group` problem.) Should I elaborate?

Comment: Note that the title of this question is misleading. As far as I understand according to your last comment, you are not primarily interested in duplicates but rather in the latest entry for each distinct id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Postgresql's `DISTINCT ON` feature in conjunction with an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) 
       id, 
       status, 
       source
FROM   data
ORDER  BY id, status
```

Here is an aequivalent query that does not use any Postgres specific features:

```
SELECT id, 
       status, 
       source
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               status, 
               source,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY status) AS n 
        FROM   data) AS sub
WHERE   sub.n = 1
```

The `ORDER BY` clause feels a bit clumsy with this data set (in both query variants) because it uses alphabetical ordering in order to express the semantic ordering of "`new` is newer than `old`". The ordering would feel more natural if we used a timestamp column `created_at` (or similar) instead of the `status` column.